# OpenCV VideoCapture from Gstream Pipeline and QTImage Conversion Problems

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

Here are my problems:

1. Whether I use the pipeline to Gstreamer or not; the output is always the same and it is broken. Why the pipeline has no effect on the captures?
2. I tried different color formats both for `cvtColor` and for `QImage.format` parts of the codes. There is sth. wrong with getting the capture from the cam and the conversion between that and QImage. But I could not figure how to solve it.

Firstly, here is the Gstream live cam capture from command line:

[image]

So; pretty normal when opening the gstream from cmd.

When it comes to OpenCV

Here is the code piece:

```
cv::Mat frame;
//cv::VideoCapture cap; //I GOT THE SAME RESULTS WHEN USING THIS LINE INSTEAD.
const char *pipeline = " tcambin serial=40120113 ! video/x-raw, format=BGRx, width=640,height=480, framerate=60/1 ! videoconvert ! appsink";
cv::VideoCapture *cap = new cv::VideoCapture(pipeline,cv::CAP_GSTREAMER);

*cap >> frame;

QImage imgOriginal = QImage(frame.data,frame.cols,frame.rows,QImage::Format_BGR888).rgbSwapped();
emit originalImage(imgOriginal);
```

Here is the output:

[image]

About the camera; I listed the formats from cmd that the camera uses, which were:

```
Available gstreamer-1.0 caps:
video/x-bayer,format=grbg,width=1280,height=960,framerate={60/1,50/1,40/1,30/1,20/1,10/1};
video/x-bayer,format=grbg,width=1280,height=720,framerate={80/1,60/1,50/1,40/1,30/1,20/1,10/1};
video/x-bayer,format=grbg,width=1024,height=768,framerate={80/1,70/1,60/1,40/1,30/1,20/1,10/1};
video/x-bayer,format=grbg,width=640,height=480,framerate={120/1,90/1,60/1,30/1,15/1,10/1};
video/x-raw,format=GRAY8,width=1280,height=960,framerate={60/1,50/1,40/1,30/1,20/1,10/1};
video/x-raw,format=GRAY8,width=1280,height=720,framerate={80/1,60/1,50/1,40/1,30/1,20/1,10/1};
video/x-raw,format=GRAY8,width=1024,height=768,framerate={80/1,70/1,60/1,40/1,30/1,20/1,10/1};
video/x-raw,format=GRAY8,width=640,height=480,framerate={120/1,90/1,60/1,30/1,15/1,10/1};
video/x-raw,format=GRAY16_LE,width=1280,height=960,framerate={70/1,60/1,50/1,40/1,30/1,20/1,10/1};
video/x-raw,format=GRAY16_LE,width=640,height=480,framerate={120/1,90/1,60/1,30/1,15/1,10/1}
```

So, seeing that GRBG (bayer) formats, someone suggested that could may be problematic.
So I tried to change the lines like this:

```
*cap >> frame;
cvtColor(frame, frame, cv::COLOR_BayerGR2BGR);
```

I know the VideoCapture `is using BGR already` but the output was improved after that(at least not broken into pieces):

[image]

**Note: The code was working excellent with the previous camera.**

This was my progress, I should get the captures exactly like that gstream output from the cmd but couldn't figure how to do that.

**Update**

I tried all the other Bayer conversions, they did not work. They are either too yellowish or blueish, but not close to the original capture.

Comment: Seems to be the wrong image format. Maybe something like Binning is enabled by default?

Comment: Can you show the gstreamer pipeline command thst generated the first image? I think your debayering might be the wrong bayer-pattern.

Comment: Try different bayer codes from this list https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html , since here it looks like they might be ambiguous: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/19629

Comment: OpenCV's debayering conversion codes are... wrong. someone implemented stuff and either mixed up the terminology, or considered an offset 2x2 area of the pattern for the naming. try them all (that make sense). I remember discussion and investigation of this several months ago.

Comment: I tried all the other Bayer conversions, they did not work. They are either too yellowish or blueish, but not close to the original capture.